# Projects not running when change the directory

Tags: javascript, react-native, build.gradle

I am a newbie in RN. I started learning React native in the month of may with the help of google. First i stored my react native projects in drive C and whenever i clone an existing project from Github i also stored it on same drive and they are working fine. But last week i change my working directory to G. And it is suddenly started giving me issues as my existing projects that i imported from drive C stopped working and also the projects that i clone from github also not running. Both giving me the following error:
`Task :app:installDebug FAILED`
But when i create a new project using `npx react-native run-android` it run.

Kindly tell me what's the issue is and what thing i am doing wrong.

Comment: if you changed the dir you may have to update it in a few places.  Hope this helps https://dev.to/iacopo87/react-native-how-to-change-the-default-folder-structure-47lf

Comment: Might be it is just failing to install, if so uninstall the previous app in the device any try.

Comment: @Cameron already done these steps, not working